# Can't find cache key in Cache redirect

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, aws-appsync

When I start my react-native app I wan't to query "everything" for an offline experience.

So I

```
query all {
  groups {
    ...GroupF
  }

  persons {
    ...PersonF
  } 
}${PERSON_ITEM}${GROUP_ITEM}
```

PersonF and GroupF are fragments.

The first view has a list of groups, each person can belong to a group. When the user clicks on an group the query looks like:

```
persons($group: ID) {
  persons(group: $group) {
    ...PersonsF
  }
}${PERSON_ITEM}
```

But my cacheRedirects just does not reflect the same data as is returned.

I know this because i console.log out the response in my component wrapper (it looks excellent here)

but in my

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  cacheRedirects: {
    Query: {
      persons: (_, args, {getCacheKeys}) => {
       // I have tried everything here but nothing maps correctly
       // I have tried getCacheKey({__typename: 'Person', id: args.group})
       // I have tried following the apollo documentation
       // No luck, it just can't find the group
       // Using the chrome dev tools I don't see persons having groups
       const a = getCacheKey({__typename: 'Person', id: args.group});
       // Console.log(a) is:
       // {generated: false, id: "Person:9", type: "id", typename "Person"}
      }
    } 
  }
});
```

**Do you have any suggestions on how I can write a proper cache redirects persons query?**

Help really really really appreciated

|1| https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#cacheRedirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the fact we used the **id** field in the Person, since we stoped using the field it works perfectly.